# Array.prototype.filter() doesn't work on array of objects because of different quotes

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm using express and mongoose and I want to filter an array that comes from a database. The objects from the database are formatted differently than the object in my request. I believe this is why it doesn't filter as it should. How do I fix this?

```
router.post("/deleteTask", auth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findById(req.user);
    console.log(req.body.task);
    console.log(user.tasks.filter(task => task !== req.body.task));
    await User.updateOne(
      { _id: req.user },
      { tasks: user.tasks.filter(task => task !== req.body.task) },
      { upsert: true }
    );
    res.json(true);
  } catch (error) {
    res.json({
      message: error.message
    });
  }
});
```

first console.log logs `{ title: 'test888', description: '' }`

second console.log logs `... {"title":"test888","description":""} ...`

Comment: quotes mean nothing... but looks like you are trying to check two objects which is never going to be true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing two objects. That will always return `false`, unless the objects are *the same*.

Have a look at this for more detail: [How to determine equality for two JavaScript objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-to-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects)

In your case, a quick way to solve your problem would be to compare titles in your filter function:

`task => task.title !== req.body.task.title`

Comment: better use would be an id. if available.

Comment: Yes, an id would be ideal if available, since titles might be repeated.

Comment: Thanks! I have implemented ids and now use ids to delete things. However, for some reason, when I use the same code in my Redux reducer, it works correctly. Why is that?